# verilog error:syntax error-Is there a missing '::'?

Tags: verilog

> ** Error: line(27): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='.
>
> ** Error: line(27): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'Q'. Is there a missing '::'?

```
module LS161a(
    input [3:0] D,        // Parallel Input
    input CLK,            // Clock
    input CLR_n,          // Active Low Asynchronous Reset
    input LOAD_n,         // Enable Parallel Input
    input ENP,            // Count Enable Parallel
    input ENT,            // Count Enable Trickle
    output [3:0]Q,        // Parallel Output    
    output RCO            // Ripple Carry Output (Terminal Count)
); 
wire [3:0]temp;

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    if (CLR_n==0)
        temp<=0000;
    else if (CLR_n==1)
    begin
        if (LOAD_n == 0)

            temp<=D;
        else if (ENP==1 & ENT==1)
            temp<=temp+1;
    end 
end
Q=temp;                                 //line 27
RCO = temp[3]& temp[2]& temp[1]& temp[0]& ENT;
//end 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error points to the line:

```
Q=temp;
```

You need to use the `assign` keyword for continuous assignments to a `wire`.  You probably also got a similar error for `RCO`.  I also got a 3rd compile error for the `temp` assignment.  Since it is assigned in an always block, it must be declared as a `reg` instead of a `wire`.  I changed 3 lines in your code to fix all these errors (marked by `////`).

```
module LS161a(
    input [3:0] D,        // Parallel Input
    input CLK,            // Clock
    input CLR_n,          // Active Low Asynchronous Reset
    input LOAD_n,         // Enable Parallel Input
    input ENP,            // Count Enable Parallel
    input ENT,            // Count Enable Trickle
    output [3:0]Q,        // Parallel Output    
    output RCO            // Ripple Carry Output (Terminal Count)
); 
reg [3:0]temp; ////

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    if (CLR_n==0)
        temp<=0000;
    else if (CLR_n==1)
    begin
        if (LOAD_n == 0)

            temp<=D;
        else if (ENP==1 & ENT==1)
            temp<=temp+1;
    end 
end

assign Q=temp; ////
assign RCO = temp[3]& temp[2]& temp[1]& temp[0]& ENT; ////
endmodule
```